# Should the case of the title of the original publication be preserved in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, capitalization

In the LaTeX template I'm using, the titles of the publications listed in the bibliography are automatically set to all lowercase (except for the first word). I was surprised by this as I would have guessed the case of the original title should be preserved. Should I change it so the original case is used, or is this behavior completely typographically sound?

Comment: Not really a TeX question. More of a style one. If you are submitting to a journal, then it is best to read their guidelines or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 11):

There are two different issues here:

```
1.  The capitalization of the title in the database.

2.  The capitalization of the title in the list of references.
```

The second depends on the "house style" of the journal *where* the citation list is published, not the journal where the original paper was.  Therefore BibTeX and biblatex try to change the capitalization according to the style.  In most cases it means lower casing aricle titles, but uppercasing the book titles.  You need to help the computer to keep the proper names etc. uppercase, like this:

```
title = {Some Notes on {N}ewtonian Laws}
```

The capitalization in the database should be the following:  uppercasing all letters but 'the', 'an', etc., and braces for letters that must not be lowercased, as in the example.

Comment: What if the original article had an all-lowercase (except for the first letter) title? Should I still uppercase the letters in the database?

Comment: Yes, this is what the rules say...